# Access Target Disk 2nd Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, target-disk-mode

How does one connect using Terminal to a mounted Macintosh HD when there are 2 drives with the same name?

```
$ cd /Volumes
$ ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel     1 Jul 27 19:10 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxr-xr-x  35 robertsd  staff  1120 Jul 27 17:09 Macintosh HD 1
```

I am actually trying to access the 2nd (sick) Macbook's ~/Library via Thunderbolt cable with:

```
/Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/Users/robertsd/Library/
```

but this finds the 1st Macintosh HD.

Comment: #3 in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/200654/34575) unlocks the Finder to show hidden files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second hard drive is mounted as "Machintosh HD 1". You should be able to access the User Library data by navigating to it with the command

```
cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/robertsd/Library"
```

(or what username you are trying to access).

Comment: I'll be darned!  This didn't want to work last night, but is the simple answer.